# OSMdroid throw Bitmap Exception

Tags: android, osmdroid

I'm using offline maps to display using `OSMdroid`, Sometimes Whenever at places I try to zoom or pan where maptiles are not available my app crashes.

Here is stack trace:

`07-01 13:24:01.625: E/AndroidRuntime(13443): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-01 13:24:01.625: E/AndroidRuntime(13443):    at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfCannotDraw(Canvas.java:1083)
07-01 13:24:01.625: E/AndroidRuntime(13443):    at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1201)
07-01 13:24:01.625: E/AndroidRuntime(13443):    at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.MapTileProviderBase$ZoomInTileLooper.handleTile(MapTileProviderBase.java:343)
07-01 13:24:01.625: E/AndroidRuntime(13443):    at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.MapTileProviderBase$ScaleTileLooper.handleTile(MapTileProviderBase.java:292)
07-01 13:24:01.625: E/AndroidRuntime(13443):    at org.osmdroid.util.TileLooper.loop(TileLooper.java:34)
07-01 13:24:01.625: E/AndroidRuntime(13443):    at org.osmdroid.tileprovider.MapTileProviderBase.rescaleCache(MapTileProviderBase.java:248)
07-01 13:24:01.625: E/AndroidRuntime(13443):    at org.osmdroid.views.MapView.setZoomLevel(MapView.java:368)
07-01 13:24:01.625: E/AndroidRuntime(13443):    at org.osmdroid.views.MapController.setZoom(MapController.java:182)
07-01 13:24:01.625: E/AndroidRuntime(13443):    at org.osmdroid.views.MapController.onAnimationEnd(MapController.java:263)
07-01 13:24:01.625: E/AndroidRuntime(13443):    at org.osmdroid.views.MapController$MyZoomAnimatorListener.onAnimationEnd(MapController.java:280)
07-01 13:24:01.625: E/AndroidRuntime(13443):    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.endAnimation(ValueAnimator.java:1056)
07-01 13:24:01.625: E/AndroidRuntime(13443):    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.access$400(ValueAnimator.java:50)
07-01 13:24:01.625: E/AndroidRuntime(13443):    at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.doAnimationFrame(ValueAnimator.java:644)
07-01 13:24:01.625: E/AndroidRuntime(13443):    at android.animation.ValueAnimator$AnimationHandler.run(ValueAnimator.java:660)
07-01 13:24:01.625: E/AndroidRuntime(13443):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
07-01 13:24:01.625: E/AndroidRuntime(13443):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
07-01 13:24:01.625: E/AndroidRuntime(13443):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
07-01 13:24:01.625: E/AndroidRuntime(13443):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
07-01 13:24:01.625: E/AndroidRuntime(13443):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-01 13:24:01.625: E/AndroidRuntime(13443):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-01 13:24:01.625: E/AndroidRuntime(13443):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-01 13:24:01.625: E/AndroidRuntime(13443):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-01 13:24:01.625: E/AndroidRuntime(13443):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 13:24:01.625: E/AndroidRuntime(13443):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-01 13:24:01.625: E/AndroidRuntime(13443):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-01 13:24:01.625: E/AndroidRuntime(13443):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-01 13:24:01.625: E/AndroidRuntime(13443):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a `NullPointerException`. You are missing the tile corresponding to this location at this level of zoom, but this case is not handled in your code.

The renderer expects the tile's `Bitmap` to exist and therefore crashes when attempting to display it.

Comment: any of the exception doesn't show my code bug, all the traces points to either library or java. It doesn't correspond to any part of my written code.

Comment: and also, you notice some of my other threads, where I actually render all the bitmaps. See:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872164/load-osmdroid-offline-custom-maptiles-faster

Comment: Comment 1: Yes, this is because the rendering itself is performed by the lib. However, your code can prevent the lib from attempting to display non-existant tiles. Try to provide a default gray empty tile for missing locations, for example.
Comment 2: will have a look asap, I'm unfortunately not able to do so right now.